# Doxygen FILE_VERSION_FILTER

Tags: documentation, doxygen

Got the Git command "git log --format='%H' -1" in the settings of FILE_VERSION_FILTER and Doxywizard log also shows while building the specific git commit hash to every file. How can I use now the git commit hash in the comments of the specific files? Thanks!

Version: 1.9.3

Edit:
Doxywizard gets every latest git commit hash from every file (see picture). I want to add this hash into the source file comments of specific functions as version number.

Something like: \version {latest git hash of this file}

[image]

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want. can you give a small example (source + the settings different from the default doxygen settings i.e. the result of `doxygen -x` and a, mock-up, of where you miss the required information ). Note the current version of doxygen is 1.9.4 (though won't influence your question).

Comment: I saw your edit, where exactly do you want to have have the version number, with the detailed description of a specific function?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to have the git commit hash as version number in the function description. Is there something like a "version variable" from doxygen? Or another possibility to use the git hash? Took already a look into the doxygen documentation but found nothing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I think that with git it is quite useless to have the commit hash for every function / specific functions / file  as the commit has is the same for the complete blob (or did I miss something). This is contrary to e.g. CVS where each file has his own commit number. In case of git I would expect that the user would have a (CMake) script that calculates the commit hash and places this in e.g. an `ALIASES` (in the doxygen settings file) and uses this new command to show the hash.

Comment: Thanks @albert. Is there any way to use the ouput of FILE_VERSION_FILTER? If not I will create a makefile and ALIASES.

Comment: A direct use of the `FILE_VERSION_FILTER` is not known to me, so you will need an `ALIASES`